# Measure HTTP request load time using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: http, networking, qt4, qtwebkit

I'm trying to implement simple webprofiler using QtWebKit (by extending Ghost.py). I need to measure when each HTTP request started and finished.

I can use `finished` signal from `QNetworkAccessManager` to get when request ended, but how do i know when request started? `QNetworkAccessManager` makes async requests and also uses queue, but there is no `started` signal. When is request actually started and how I can attach to this event?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to make a solution fit the problem.

Comment: What do you mean? QtWebkit uses QNetworkAccessManager to make requests, I can't see any possible way around it.

Comment: QtWebKit has it's own debugging tool, where you can see each request and time it took to fullfill it. Check in sources how did they do this in QtWebKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible resolution is to create subclass under `QNetworkAccessManager` and pass it to `QWebPage`. Inherited class should override method `createRequest`, which can measure start time of the HTTP request.